# Multiple widget changes based on one button event in Kivy

Tags: events, button, kivy

I'm trying to build this application which contains multiple buttons. I can bind each button event to a callback but I am not able to change the state (namely the label) of any other button except for the one that fired the event. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a reference to the other button, then you can do `other_button.text = 'whatever'`.

The way to do this depends on how you've constructed the program. For instance, if you constructed in the program in kv language, you can give your buttons ids with `id: some_id` and refer to them in the callback with stuff like `on_press: some_id.do_something()`.

In pure python, you could keep references to the button in the parent class when you create them (e.g. `self.button = Button()`) so that the callback can reference `self.button` to change it. Obviously that's a trivial example, but the general idea lets you accomplish anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the official way, but try out the following code. It will change the text property of the buttons...

Ezs.kv file:

```
 #:kivy 1.8.0

<Ezs>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 0
        spacing: 6

        #choose
        Button:
            id: btn_1
            text: 'text before'
            on_press: btn_2.text = 'Whatever'
            on_release: self.text = 'Who-Hoo'   
        #choose
        Button:
            id: btn_2
            text: 'Press this'
            on_release: self.text = 'HEEYY'
            on_press: btn_1.text = 'text after'
```

.py file:

```
class Ezs(BoxLayout):


class EzsApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Ezs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    EzsApp().run()
```